# reset value after checking onchange value in select in jsp

Tags: javascript

in here I would like to check  on change value in calendar then reset the old value.But it couldn't be.it checks the value in javascript function but after that it reset the new value.But i want old value there.Mainly it checks the select date whether before the set date, if yes give alert.But then it change to new value.i want old value again after the alert.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_from(a,b,c) {
    var date=Date.parse(a);
    var date2=Date.parse(b);
    var date3=Date.parse(c);

    if(date3<date || date3>date2){
        alert("Please select date betwen"+" "+a+" "+"and"+" "+b);
        return false;
    }       
}
</script>

<input id="date_1" class="input-medium ndshaatepicker-basic" type="text" value=<%=rs.getString("start_date")%> onchange="check_from('<%=rs.getString("start_date") %>','<%=rs.getString("end_date") %>',this.value)">
```

Comment: Please, improve your question. It's impossible to understand what your code does, how does it, what is failing, and so on. Please, follow the advices in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: after checking value in input using java script function i have to replace old value but it change to a new value.

Comment: This doesn't help. Please, improve the question itselft, don't simply add comments. Make it much more clear what is the initial state, the event, and the expected final state. If you don't improve the question, it will be probably closed because it's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "data" Attributes to store the "old" / initial value and extend the function with one param to get it know which id should be read..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_from(a,b,c,elemID){

var initialvalue=document.getElementById(elemID).getAttribute('data-initial');
var date=Date.parse(a);
var date2=Date.parse(b);
var date3=Date.parse(c);

if(date3<date || date3>date2){
    document.getElementById(elemID).value=initialvalue
    alert("Please select date betwen"+" "+a+" "+"and"+" "+b);
    return false;
} 
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="date_1" data-initial="5" value="5" onChange="check_from('1','10',this.value,'date_1')">
```